Pay-off Call and Put Options on Futures
I was trying to prove the put-call parity for options where the underlying is a futures contract. However, in doing so, I got a bit lost as to what the payoff is of the call (and put) options at maturity T.
As far as I understand it now:

If the call option expires in the money, you obtain the futures contract value $V_{T} = S_T - F_T$ at expiry (hence no discount term) minus the strike price K, hence the payoff would be $C_T = V_T - K = S_T - F_T - K$ (For put, $P_T = K - V_T$ if expire in the money).

Now my question is:

Can anyone state whether this is correct?
If correct (or incorrect), how would one prove the put-call parity with futures as the underlying.


Note that at maturity $S_T-F_T$ is zero, so that cannot be right.

@nbbo2 is that because daily-margining and hence the value of the contract ($V_t$) made to be 0 every day, hence also at expiration?

When a call on a future is exercised, you receive a long position in futures (worth 0 at that time) and a cash amount equal to the most recent future price $F_T$ minus the strike K.

So assuming the long position is closed out immediately (with no loss or gain) the payoff is very similar to the stock call payoff namely $\max(0,F_T-K)$ where $F$ appears instead of $S$.
